# How to fix User interaction disclosure : Eligibility issue in Play Store Family Requirement Policy?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Issue:

You must accurately disclose the app's interactive elements on the content rating questionnaire in the Play Console, including whether:

- users can interact or exchange information;
- your app shares user-provided personal information with third parties
- youur app shares the user's physical location with other users

.
To resolve this issue, please remove violating elements from your app, retake the content rating questionnaire and/or review your responses regarding the interactive elements of your app. For more details, you can refer to requirement #2 of the Designed for Families Requirements.

I have answered the questionnaire correctly. Users can post about their work in the community, and we don't share any personal info with third parties and users can't share physical location with other users. I have answered the questionnaire correctly. I am unable to figure out what's the issue! It's been more than 15 days. Please help out.

We use firebase firestore for backend and uxcam for analytics

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic